# Append YouTube video with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I want to make some kind of player for a website I'm making. And the point is that a user clicks on one div, and then new div is created that will contain the YouTube video.

```
$('.slika').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('body').prepend('<div class="player"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
});
```

And when I try to do this I get a "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6YLFbFh3tw does not permit cross-origin framing." message. Tried to Google the answer but nothing is helping me.
One more thing, when I do this on my index page, without "prepend" it works.

Comment: The message should be pretty clear, Youtube has added headers that disallows any framing of their content.

Comment: They do however offer embed codes for embedding videoes on your site

Comment: It works when I use <object> but W3school says that's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, mistake was using normal YouTube URL.
I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6YLFbFh3tw
I should use: https://www.youtube.com/embed/g6YLFbFh3tw